# Undefined Error When Trying to Get React Navigation Params

Tags: javascript, react-native, routes

I'm having an issue. I am getting the error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_route$params.originPlace')`.

```
import { View, Text, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import HomeMap from "../components/HomeMap/HomeMap";
import RideTypes from "../components/RideTypes/RideTypes";
import styles from "./styles.js";
import RouteMap from "../components/RouteMap/RouteMap";
import { useRoute } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
    
const SearchResult = (props) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
   
  const route = useRoute();
    
  console.log(route.params);
    
  const { originPlace, destinationPlace } = route.params;
    
  return (
    <View>
      <View style={{ height: Dimensions.get("window").height - 400 }}>
        <RouteMap origin={originPlace} destination={destinationPlace} />
      </View>
      <View>
        <RideTypes />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
    
export default SearchResult;
```

Heres the other file where I m taking the origin and destination. But I don't know what is wrong in here. I m not able to figure out. Help!

```
import { View, Text, Image, FlatList } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE, Marker } from "react-native-maps";
import cars from "../../../assets/data/cars";
import MapViewDirections from "react-native-maps-directions";
import {GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY} from "@env";

const RouteMap = ({origin,destination}) => {

    const originLoc = { 
      latitude: origin.details.geometry.location.lat,
      longitude: origin.details.geometry.location.lng,
    }
    const destinationLoc = {
      latitude:destination.details.geometry.location.lat,
      longitude:destination.details.geometry.location.lng,

    }

    console.log(originLoc);  
  return (
    <MapView
      style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
      provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
      showsUserLocation={true}
      initialRegion={{
        latitude: 28.450627,
        longitude: -16.263045,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0222,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
      }}
    >
      <MapViewDirections
        origin={originLoc}
        destination={destinationLoc}
        apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
        strokeWidth={3}
        strokeColor="hotpink"
      />
      <Marker
          coordinate={originLoc}
          title={'Origin'}
      />
      <Marker
          coordinate={destinationLoc}
          title={'Destination'}
      />
    </MapView>
  );
};

export default RouteMap;
```

And here is the destination Search js file which will redirect to search result once origin and destination selected from google apis.

```
import { View, Text, TextInput, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from "react-native-google-places-autocomplete";
import { GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY } from "@env";
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

import styles from './styles';
import PlaceRow from './PlaceRow.js';



const DestinationSearch = (props) => {

  navigation = useNavigation();
  const homePlace = {
    description: 'Home',
    geometry: { location: { lat: 48.8152937, lng: 2.4597668 } },
  };
  const workPlace = {
    description: 'Work',
    geometry: { location: { lat: 48.8496818, lng: 2.2940881 } },
  };

  const checkNavigation = () => {
    if (originPlace && destinationPlace) {
      navigation.navigate('SearchResult'), {
        originPlace,
        destinationPlace,
      }
  }

  }
  
    const [originPlace, setOriginPlace] = useState( null ) ;
    const [destinationPlace, setDestinationPlace] = useState( null );

    useEffect(() =>{
      checkNavigation();
       

    }, [originPlace,destinationPlace]);


  return (

      <SafeAreaView>
    <View style= {styles.container}>
    {/* From */}
    <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
          backgroundColor= "#eee"
          nearbyPlacesAPI="GooglePlacesSearch"
          placeholder="From"
          styles={{
            textInput: styles.textInput,
            container: styles.autoCompleteContainer,
            listView: styles.listView,
            separator: styles.separator,
          }}
          onPress={(data , details = null) => {
              setOriginPlace({data, details});
            
          }}
          renderRow={(data) =><PlaceRow data={data}/>}
          fetchDetails={true}
          enablePoweredByContainer={false}
          currentLocation={true}
          currentLocationLabel='Current Location'
          query={{
            key: GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY,
            language: "en",
          }}
          renderRow={(data) => <PlaceRow data={data}/>}
          renderDescription={(data) => data.description || data.vicinity}
          predefinedPlaces={[homePlace, workPlace]}

        />
        {/* Where To */}
        <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
          backgroundColor= "#eee"
          nearbyPlacesAPI="GooglePlacesSearch"
          placeholder="Where To?"
          styles={{
            textInput: styles.textInput,
            container: {
              ...styles.autoCompleteContainer,
              top: 50},
            listView: {...styles.listView,
            top: 50,
            },
            separator: styles.separator,
          }}
          onPress={(data , details = null) => {
              setDestinationPlace({data, details});
            
          }}
          renderRow={(data) =><PlaceRow data={data}/>}
          fetchDetails={true}
          returnKeyType={"Search"}
          enablePoweredByContainer={false}
          query={{
            key: GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY,
            language: "en",
          }}
        />
        {/* Circle near origin Input */}
        <View style = {styles.circle}/>
        
        {/* Line between dots */}
        <View style = {styles.line}/>


        {/* Square near destination Input */}
        <View style = {styles.square}/>


     
    </View>
  


        
     
    
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

export default DestinationSearch;
```

Comment: Are you navigating to the page with the params `originPlace` and `destinationPlace`

Comment: Yes. Here the other File code:
const RouteMap = ({origin,destination}) => {

    const originLoc = { 
      latitude: origin.details.geometry.location.lat,
      longitude: origin.details.geometry.location.lng,
    }
    const destinationLoc = {
      latitude:destination.details.geometry.location.lat,
      longitude:destination.details.geometry.location.lng,

    }
//Rest of the Code

Comment: Where is the code that navigates to the SearchResult screen? Add all relevant code to the original post please (not the comments)

Comment: Kindly check the code above again. I have edited and added the code again of Destinationsearch.js and HomeSearch.js and routmap.js . If you need more code please let me know. Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The Mistake was in DestinationSearch 
Mistake:
 const checkNavigation = () => {
    if (originPlace && destinationPlace) {
      navigation.navigate('SearchResult'), {
        originPlace,
        destinationPlace,
      }
  }

  }
Solution: 
 const checkNavigation = () => {
    if (originPlace && destinationPlace) {
      navigation.navigate("SearchResult",
        {
          originPlace,
          destinationPlace,
        })
    }
  }
```